# BEST WAY ??? automated-tests with powershell-scripts in internetexplorer (Windows7)

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, powershell, permissions, automated-tests

Currently I create a program, which shall automated-tests. To allow for this problem-free I must deactivate Silverlight (because my scripts don´t work in windows7 otherwise).
Is there a chance to do this, without the user must admin-permissions have?

If yes: what chance is it?
If no:  Can I create the program only for users with admin-permissions or have I other chances (for example: manipulate Silverlight, so that my Scripts work with Silverlight ...)?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need Addons in your IE you could just start it with the -extoff parameter which disables all addons, including Silverlight.
In Powershell it might look like this:

```
Start-Process iexplore.exe -ArgumentList -extoff
```